# Regex for: Must contain a numeric, excluding "SomeText1"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regex pattern (must be a single pattern) to match any text that contains a number, excluding a specific literal (i.e. "SomeText1").

I have the match any text containing a number part:

```
^.*[0-9]+.*$
```

But am having a problem excluding a specific literal.

**Update:** This is for .NET Regex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which language are you writing?  Sometimes regex syntax can differ between languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a verbose regex:

```
^              # Start of string
(?=.*[0-9])    # Assert presence of at least one digit
(?!SomeText1$) # Assert that the string is not "SomeText1"
.*             # If so, then match any characters
$              # until the end of the string
```

If your regex flavor doesn't support those:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?!SomeText1$).*$
```

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - Thanks, but this should match "SomeText1234" and "1234SomeText1" but doesn't.

Comment: Oh, so `SomeText12` is ok, only `SomeText1` isn't? No problem. Will edit.

Comment: Uh, sorry, I'm still confused. Why does `1234SomeText1` match? Do you mean that `SomeText1` is only forbidden if it's the entire string?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - Awesome, thanks for this.  FYI, I also put `\b` before SomeText1 to allow "123SomeText1": `^(?=.*[0-9])(?!.*\bSomeText1\b).*$`

Comment: @Jerad: I've re-edited my answer after finally understanding what you had meant (sorry, your question was written perfectly, I just misinterpreted it).

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - Bingo, that did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use negative-look-ahead:

```
^(?!.*?SomeText1).*?[0-9]+.*$
```